# wordpress remove the base link from (PopUp by Supsystic) plugin

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a website in wordpress where i have a plugin(PopUp by Supsystic)(http://www.kennethbarnes.org/) this plug popup a dialogue box where i have three links as in the picture. this links are the links of another website but this but this link is also contain the name of current domain how to remove that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code will hide those links. It selects the p container elements for the links and subsequently the links. You will need to enter it in the admin section of WordPress.

```
.ppsRightCol p {
    display: none;
}
```

Find the part of your theme options for 'Edit CSS' and insert the above.

Comment: i dont want to hide the links i need that links but this plug using the base url like i need this website link (www.southerngirlzrealestategroup.com) but when i click it return me (http://www.kennethbarnes.org/www.southerngirlzrealestategroup.com)
i want to remove base url(http://www.kennethbarnes.org/)